# Vagrant won't start on Windows CMD (Errno::EACCES)

Tags: windows, cmd, vagrant

So I am using the Vagrant Box gotten from this site: https://github.com/edx/configuration/wiki/edX-Developer-Stack

I set it up per the instructions (Although modified, since I am using Windows CMD), and when I type in vagrant up, I get this output:

```
C:\Users\User\My Documents\MOOCS\WindowsEDX\my-workspace\my-edx-workspace\devsta
ck>vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
[default] Importing base box 'empanada-devstack'...
[default] Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
[default] Setting the name of the VM...
[default] Clearing any previously set forwarded ports...
[default] Destroying VM and associated drives...
[default] Running cleanup tasks for 'shell' provisioner...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/util/platform.
rb:75:in `open': Permission denied - C:/Users/User/My Documents (Errno::EACCES)
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/platform.rb:75:in `entries'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/platform.rb:75:in `block in fs_real_path'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/platform.rb:74:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/platform.rb:74:in `fs_real_path'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/synced_folders.rb:56:in `block (2 levels) in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/synced_folders.rb:40:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/synced_folders.rb:40:in `block in call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/synced_folders.rb:39:in `each'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/synced_folders.rb:39:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/synced_folder_cleanup.rb:28:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/prepare_nfs_valid_ids.rb:12:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/handle_forwarded_port_collisions.rb:118:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/prepare_forwarded_port_collision_params.rb:30:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/env_set.rb:19:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/provision.rb:52:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/clear_forwarded_ports.rb:13:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/set_name.rb:48:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/clean_machine_folder.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/check_accessible.rb:18:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:95:in `block in finalize_action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/call.rb:51:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/config_validate.rb:25:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builtin/call.rb:57:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/plugins/provi
ders/virtualbox/action/check_virtualbox.rb:17:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/warden.rb:34:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/builder.rb:116:in `call'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `block in run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/u
til/busy.rb:19:in `busy'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/a
ction/runner.rb:69:in `run'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/m
achine.rb:147:in `action'
        from C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/vagrant-1.4.1/lib/vagrant/b
atch_action.rb:63:in `block (2 levels) in run'
```

I'm not too sure what this means, or if it has anything to do with Ruby. When I ran this on Cygwin, it worked fine, but for testing purposes, I have to do this on Windows CMD.

I have also tried disabling my anti-virus, and running CMD as administrator.  Neither worked.

Answer (score 9):

I had a similar issue. What I found is that the "My Documents" name is actually an alias for the "Documents" folder. Try changing the path, substituting "Documents" for "My Documents".

Comment: Thanks - this worked for me.  I just needed to change to C:\Users\myname instead of C:\Documents and Settings\myname before running Vagrant.

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem using a different image.  You might try moving your working folder from My Documents to a folder path that does not have spaces in it.  It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Vagrant goes through each part of the path and verifies that it is properly cased. This requires going to each part and listing the directory. It looks like your user on Windows doesn't have read access for that directory for some reason, which is causing this to fail.

The fact a stack trace is shown is a bug with Vagrant, and I will fix that.

The solution is to check the permissions of every component of the synced folder so verify your user has read permissions on the directory.

Comment: Shouldn't the fact that I ran CMD as an administrator override that?

I'm more used to Linux/Unix permissions than Windows, but like I said, due to testing purposes, I have to do this on Windows